# PHP webpage downloads instead of opens in browser (nginx, php on debian10 server)

Tags: debian, php, nginx, certbot

I have a server running Debian 10. I have installed nginx (1.18.0) and php and php-fpm (7.4.28). Following this guide https://landchad.net/index I was able to get html website with certification by certbot running. Then I wanted to use php to have menu on my website dynamic. When I go to the webpage it downloads instead of opening up.

My file tree is as follows: my webpage is stored in ***/var/www/dragallur***, there is a file ***phpinfo.php*** with the following code (if I type ***dragallur.xyz/phpinfo.php*** it asks me to download the webpage):

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

In the directory ***/etc/nginx/sites-available*** there are two files, ***default*** and ***mywebsite***, ***default*** has following contents:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.php index.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~ /.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;}}
```

And the file mywebsite:

```
server {
    server_name dragallur.xyz ;
    root /var/www/dragallur ;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html ;
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404 ;
            #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }
    
    location ~ /.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }

listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dragallur.xyz/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dragallur.xyz/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot}

server {
if ($host = dragallur.xyz) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name dragallur.xyz ;
return 404; # managed by Certbot}
```

This issue seems to happen quite often to people. I have tried cleaning my cache, I have done countless changes to the two files above but I still get the same problem. There may be other key config files so just tell me and I will share the contents. After every change which I think might be useful I run the command

```
systemctl restart nginx
```

Comment: Try the suggestions in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591040/nginx-serves-php-files-as-downloads-instead-of-executing-them)

Comment: @mashuptwice Ok I did what the first answer told me, than I got 502 error which was solvable by changing to corretct path of fpm sock file. Now when I type the IP address of the site I get the error "file not found" and in error log I can see that it could not find index.php even though it is in /var/www/html as defined by the file "default". Is there any way to find where is it actually searching or why it cannot be found?

Comment: Important note: it is searching in the correct directory most likely because if I put some random file name after the IP address I will get 404 not found error from nginx.

Comment: What is being downloaded - the raw PHP code or the HTML generated by the code?

Comment: @JohnHanley the HTML code with the PHP parts skipped. Meaning the already generated webpage but without CSS obviously and with PHP not there at all. When I go to the page dragallur.xyz it says "You have chosen to open: which is: application/octet-stream..." when I go to the IP address it says file not found as written in the comment above.

Comment: That means you have a **content-type** problem. Your server is returning **application/octet-stream** instead of **text/html**.

Comment: @JohnHanley content-type as in the contents of the page? Weirdly enough if I try to open dragallur.xyz/index.php I get the download query but of the index.php file, no application/octet-stream anymore.